# Getting Error while trying to up upgrade spring version from 5.1 to 5.2

Tags: spring, version, spring5

Facing this issue while trying to upgrade spring from 5.1 to 5.2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUiK1.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCM0S.png)

@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

```
@Override
public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
    final RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping = super.requestMappingHandlerMapping();
    handlerMapping.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
    handlerMapping.setUseTrailingSlashMatch(false);
    return handlerMapping;
}
```

}

This issue is setUseSuffixPatternMatch() method is deprecated from 5.2 version but can be used by giving arguments as false. I have given 'false' as argument but getting this error.

Is there any replacement methods for this methods.

And also I tried to remove setUseSuffixPatternMatch() method but I got this error

[18,66] method requestMappingHandlerMapping in class org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport cannot be applied to given types;
[ERROR]   required: org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlProvider

I'm not understanding why requestMappingHandlerMapping is not working when I try to upgrade spring 5.1 to 5.2

Comment: Please, add more details of your error. For instance, the trace.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the next block:

```
@Override
public RequestMappingHandlerMapping createRequestMappingHandlerMapping() {
    final RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping = super.createRequestMappingHandlerMapping();
    handlerMapping.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
    handlerMapping.setUseTrailingSlashMatch(false);
    return handlerMapping;
}
```

They only renamed the method

`requestMappingHandlerMapping` --> `createRequestMappingHandlerMapping`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of these deprecated methods you can use the updated ones. PFB

```
public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping(**ContentNegotiationManager mvcContentNegotiationManager,                                                       FormattingConversionService mvcConversionService,                                                                    ResourceUrlProvider mvcResourceUrlProvider**) {

    RequestMappingHandlerMapping handler = super.requestMappingHandlerMapping(m**vcContentNegotiationManager,
            mvcConversionService,
            mvcResourceUrlProvider**);

    handler.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
    handler.setAlwaysUseFullPath(true);
    return handler;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of these deprecated methods you can use the updated ones. PFB the link which gives you detailed information about the new methods available for the class.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.html